# C# list of class objects changing to match last object?

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to make an 'archive' of all past versions of a class (or struct, for that matter). But as a class is created to be added to the list, it seems the sum total of listed classes alter themselves to match.

My code goes along something like this:

```
public class State
{
  public int i;

  public State(int newI)
  {
    i = newI;
  }
}

List<State> list = new List<State>;

public void NewEntry(int x)
{
  State state = new State(x); //this is the line in question
  list.Add(state)
}
```

By the time the State constructor has executed, all states in list have been changed to match their i to the fresh value of x.

What am I missing, besides basic knowledge and understanding? :P

Comment: That's not compiling code: `new State(int X)`

Comment: That's not a struct either.

Comment: What happens if you replace `int X` in the line in question with `i`?

Comment: It'd be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are describing a problem that is not reproducible with the code that you show. So either the code is wrong(so pointless for the question) or there is no problem. Of course it could matter if it's a value type `struct` or a reference type `class`. So show the real code.

Comment: your question is not much clear.

Comment: Sorry about `new State(int X)`, I realized at the last minute that it'd be clearer than reusing i, and of course botched the translation. Should be better now.

I was originally using a struct and turned to class, so I just mentioned struct to cover my bases. Of course, I forgot to fix it in the title, too...

As for real code/minimal complete example, I can't really tell if I can cut it out from the tangle that the whole thing is. That said, the issue's been solved (and matches an answer to boot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm... Is not very clear from your example, but let me guess what the problem is.

When you add the class to the list, you may be adding a reference.

When you use:

```
State x = new State();
State b = x;
```

box "x" and "b" points to same object, x.i and b.i are the same memory.

**IF** and if State is a struct, then it's different

```
public **struct** State
{
  public int i;

  public State(int newI)
  {
    i = newI;
  }
}
```

Then

```
State x = new State();
State b = x;
```

will make a copy of every value field (like ints and doubles) and x.i will be in a different memory location than b.i

Is this related to your issue?

Comment: Turns out this was it! Strangely enough, the same issue was occurring back when it was a struct too. Either I am misreading your answer, or it shouldn't be misbehaving as a struct, which is confusing, but in any case, the question asked has been answered! Thanks, mate!

Comment: Have you tried " StateStruct copy = oldStruct; list.Add(copy); "?